# SDA SCL vs Serial

Tags: arduino, gps, serial-port, sda

I have a problem with Arduino, especially with communication. Is it possible for 2 types of communications to affect one another? I use 3 modules: HTU21D, GPS Neo M8M, and MS5611. FYI MS5611 and HTU21D use I2C for communication. When I use some functions from HTU21D and MS5611, my GPS doesn't read anything.

I have tried so many libraries and the result is still the same. I use a  baudrate of 38400 bauds for this project.

Can someone help? Is it caused by an electric problem or from code? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to post your code.  The only way to determine the problem is to see you code and identify potential conflicts.

Comment: without code my only guess would be that your priorities to handle these communication are not set up right.

Answer (score 0):

I think your default I2C address of the HTU21D and GPS Neo M8M having some overlap. So during a read/write of one module, the other also wants to respond.

But share your code snippets please